# Finding the conditional extrema | Correct Method

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

**Find the conditional extrema of $ f(x,y) = x^2 + y $ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = 4$**

Do you I use the Lagrange multipliers for this?

Or do I use the partial differential method and figure out what side of the zero-point this equation falls under:

$$ f_{xx}f_{yy} - {f_{xy}}^2 $$ ?

Comment: That is an expression, not an equation. Because you have a constraint you ought to use Lagrange multipliers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:

$$\tag 1 f(x,y) = x^2 + y ~~ \mbox{subject to} ~~\phi(x) = x^2 + y^2 = 4$$

A 3D plot shows:

[image]

If we draw a contour plot of the two functions, we get:

[image]

From this plot, we see four points of interest, so we will use Lagrange Multipliers to find those and then we just need classify them as local or global min or max or not classifiable.

We can write:

$$\tag 2 F(x,y) = f + \lambda \phi = x^2 + y + \lambda(x^2 + y^2)$$

So,

$\tag 3 \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 2x (1 + \lambda) = 0 \rightarrow x = 0~ \mbox{or}~ \lambda = -1, ~\mbox{and}~$

$\tag 4 \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 1 + 2 \lambda y = 0 $

From $(3)$, we get:

$$x = 0 \rightarrow y^2 = 4 \rightarrow y = \pm 2 \rightarrow \lambda = \pm \dfrac{1}{4}$$

From $(3)$ and $(4)$, we get:

$$\lambda = -1, y = \dfrac{1}{2} \rightarrow x^2 + \dfrac{1}{4} = 4 \rightarrow x = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$$

Summarizing these results, we have the four potential critical points to investigate at:

$$(x,y) = (0,2), (0,-2), \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right),\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

Now, classify these critical points using the typical method.

You should end up with (you can actually make these out from the 3D plot above):

- Local min at $(0,2)$
- Global min at $(0,-2)$
- Global max at $\left(\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: Great write up and supplementary graphs! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Glad to hear you are finally done with that! Hope all turned out as expected and that you can get back to normalcy! Time for the showers and getting to work!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. Can you give me further information on what a conditional extrema is and in which cases (applications) it is of interest? If you don't mind, that is.

Comment: @Siyanda: Conditional extrema means that we found four critical points, but they may or may not be of any use. Only after we test them using appropriate tests can they go from 'conditional' to 'actual' critical points. In other words, we need to identify the potential critical points and then test them. These methods are typically used in applications that deal with optimization, which is a very important field. Regards

Comment: Oh, yes! This is really helpful! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Siyanda: You are very welcome! Regards